# Выпадающий список в CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Не так давно начала работу с `CakePHP`, встал вопрос, как реализовать выдающий список. Смысл списка в том чтобы пользователь выбрал пункт, а в базу ушло значения: 1,2,3 в зависимости от пункта. Как это реализуется на данном фреймворке?
Или это нужно реализовывать средствами `html <select> <option>` ?

Comment: это можно реализовать множеством способов, в том числе и select-option, которые в кейке могут быть сгенерированы с помощью `$this->Form->select("fieldame", $options, $params)`. я к тому, что то, как это реализуется в шаблоне в целом может быть никак не связано с самим фреймворком.  можете хоть аякс вызов на смену селекта повесить и каждый раз в базу писать.

Comment: нужен более конкретный вопрос, тут точного ответа не напишешь

Comment: @teran, Я реализовал это таким образом, не знаю насколько это правильный вариант  `<?php echo $this->Form->select('progrecc', array([0 => 'Progress1', 1=> 'Progress2', 2=>'Progress3']));?>` но вот теперь интересно как сделать ему placeholder. И будет ли данный список работать корректно...

Answer (score 1):

При работе с базой - достаточно просто добавить массив Options в нужный элемент формы
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ru/views/helpers/form.html#checkbox-radio-select-options